# What am I doing wrong using the iter_swap method c++?

Tags: c++, iterator

Implementing a basic bubble sort to sort my vector of Student structs by name.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

void sortStudents(std::vector<Student>& students) {

    typedef std::vector<Student>::iterator iter;

    for (iter i = students.begin(); i != students.end()-1; ++i) {
        for (iter j = i; j != students.end() - 1; ++j) {

            Student current = *i;
            Student next = *(i + 1);

            bool shouldSwap = ((next.name).compare(current.name)) < 0; // if next is before current in the alphabet

            if (shouldSwap) {
                std::iter_swap(*i, *(i + 1));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Am I completely wrong with this approach or am I missing something basic?

Note: I know the inefficiency of bubble sort, I'm just trying to understand iterators.

Comment: As it name implies, `std::iter_swap` takes iterators -- you're dereferencing them and passing the values instead.

Answer (score 3):

[`std::iter_swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iter_swap) is a special version (different than [`std::swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) which swaps actual elements), that swaps elements, where iterators point to. But you try to pass actual elements to it. So it is either:

```
std::swap(*i, *(i + 1));
```

or

```
std::iter_swap(i, i + 1);
```